# How to get the relationship between 2 random tables in relational database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My requirement is to Join table A and table D. I know there are tables B and C in between which have PK and FK relationships. I want a query to know the tables B and C and the keys involved in the relationship. I need to know this for the entire database. Database diagram will give me the relationship but I don't have permissions to view the diagram. Moreover, I need to look for each set of tables. That's why I am trying to write a query that does the job for me.

In short, if I provide Table A and Table D to the query then query should give me essential columns required (in our case B.id2,C.id3) to join A and D.

```
SELECT A.*, D.* FROM A Join B on A.id1 = B.id2 Join C on B.id2 = C.id3 Join D on C.id3 = D.id4
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If you don't have permissions to view it in the database diagram, you probably don't have permissions to query the schema. Find someone who does

Comment: run `sp_help` on the tables involved, and scroll down to the section on constraints. That will tell you what referenced and referencing objects it relates to.

Comment: @Caleth I do have permissions to query the schema.

Comment: @Xedni Thanks for the advice but I am looking for a query that does the trick. What I am trying to achieve is that a query which gives the tables involved to connect the given 2 tables.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have access to the catalog views, e.g. [`sys.foreign_keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-foreign-keys-transact-sql)? That's probably the view you want to start from. Then just export the data to a [graph database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-overview) in SQL Server 2017. Or do the equivalent processing in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Gotcha. Essentially it boils down to chaining joins to `sys.foreign_keys` to eachother. If it's a fixed number of jumps, you just join that many times. However to walk an arbitrary number of jumps requires a little bit of creativity. More so if you want to know the columns involved too. I have a script on my work computer that's pretty good for that, but I also recall it taking some time to perfect. I'll see if I can slap together something "close enough" and you might be able to run with that.

Comment: @Xedni That would be wonderful! Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pulled up the one I wrote at work; looks like I didn't actually bother with the CTE (since they're a royal pain in the butt IMHO). It's a little lengthy since it's just code I ripped from a proc. My version originally didn't include the columns, but I added them in. I just concatenate them as though they were an `ON` clause, but you can tweak that how you like.

```
use AdventureWorks2014
go

declare 
    @BaseTable nvarchar(128) = 'SalesPerson',
    @BaseTableSchema nvarchar(128) = 'Sales'

declare
    @Depth int = 0,
    @RowCount int,
    @Ident int

declare @KeyHierarchy table
(
    Depth int,
    ReferencingTableSchema nvarchar(128),
    ReferencingTableName nvarchar(128),
    ReferencingObjectId int,
    ReferencingTableNameFull as quotename(ReferencingTableSchema) + '.' + quotename(ReferencingTableName),
    ReferencedTableSchema nvarchar(128),
    ReferencedTableName nvarchar(128),
    ReferencedObjectId int,
    ReferencedTableNameFull as quotename(ReferencedTableSchema) + '.' + quotename(ReferencedTableName),
    MatchingColumns nvarchar(max)

    primary key clustered (ReferencingTableSchema, ReferencingTableName)
)

insert into @KeyHierarchy
(
    Depth,
    ReferencingTableSchema,
    ReferencingTableName,
    ReferencingObjectId
)
select
    Depth = @Depth,
    ReferencingTableSchema = @BaseTableSchema,
    ReferencingTableName = @BaseTable,
    ReferencingObjectId = object_id(@BaseTableSchema + '.' + @BaseTable)

select @RowCount = 1

while @RowCount > 0
begin

    insert into @KeyHierarchy
    (
        Depth,
        ReferencedTableSchema,
        ReferencedTableName,
        ReferencedObjectId,
        ReferencingTableSchema,
        ReferencingTableName,
        ReferencingObjectId,
    MatchingColumns
    )
    select distinct
        Depth = @Depth + 1,
        ReferencedTableSchema = object_schema_name(f.referenced_object_id),
        ReferencedTableName = object_name(f.referenced_object_id),
        ReferencedObjectId = f.referenced_object_id,
        ReferencingTableSchema = object_schema_name(f.parent_object_id),
        ReferencingTableName = object_name(f.parent_object_id),
        ReferencingObjectId = f.parent_object_id,
        MatchingColumns = stuff
            (
                (
                    select 
                        concat
                        (
                            ' and parent.', 
                            quotename(col_name(c.parent_object_id, c.parent_column_id)), 
                            ' = ',
                            'referenced.',
                            quotename(col_name(c.referenced_object_id, c.referenced_column_id))
                        )
                    from sys.foreign_key_columns c
                    where f.object_id = c.constraint_object_id
                    order by c.constraint_column_id
                    for xml path(''), type
                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 4, ''
            )
    from @KeyHierarchy k
    inner join sys.foreign_keys f
        on f.referenced_object_id = k.ReferencingObjectId
            and f.parent_object_id not in (select ReferencingObjectId from @KeyHierarchy where Depth < @Depth + 1)
    where k.Depth = @Depth

    select
        @RowCount = @@RowCount,
        @Depth += 1

end

select 
    BaseTable = @BaseTable,
    ReferencingTableNameFull,
    ReferencedTableNameFull,
    MatchingColumns,
    Depth
from @KeyHierarchy
order by Depth, ReferencingTableNameFull
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked for my case. You are a superstar :)

Answer (score 0):

This has some problems but it is a start

```
select t.name [t_name], c.name [c_name], f.* 
from sys.foreign_keys f  
join sys.tables t
  on f.parent_object_id = t.object_id 
 and f.type = 'F'
left join sys.columns c
  on c.object_id = f.referenced_object_id 
 and c.system_type_id = 56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fiddle about from this starting point:

```
with
  ForeignKeys as (
    -- All foreign keys with their associated tables and columns.
    select fk.name as ConstraintName, fk.object_id as ContraintObjectId,
      pt.name as ParentTable, pt.object_id as ParentTableObjectId, pc.name as ParentColumn, pc.column_id as ParentColumnId,
      ft.name as ForeignTable, ft.object_id as ForeignTableObjectId, fc.name as ForeignColumn, fc.column_id as ForeignColumnId
      from sys.foreign_keys as fk inner join
        sys.foreign_key_columns as fkc on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id inner join
        sys.tables as pt on pt.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id inner join
        sys.columns as pc on pc.object_id = pt.object_id and pc.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id inner join
        sys.tables as ft on ft.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id inner join
        sys.columns as fc on fc.object_id = ft.object_id and fc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id ),
  RelatedTables as (
    -- All ordered pairs of directly related tables.
    select distinct ParentTable, ParentTableObjectId, ForeignTable, ForeignTableObjectId
      from ForeignKeys ),
  RelatedTablesHierarchy as (
    -- Hierarchy of related tables.
    -- Start from each distinct table that has a foreign key relation ...
    select ParentTable, ParentTableObjectId, ForeignTable, ForeignTableObjectId,
      Cast( ParentTable + '»' + ForeignTable as NVarChar(4000) ) as Path
      from RelatedTables
    union all
    -- ... and add any other table to which the foreign table is related.
    select RTH.ParentTable, RTH.ParentTableObjectId, RT.ForeignTable, RT.ForeignTableObjectId,
      Cast( Path + '»' + RT.ForeignTable as NVarChar(4000) )
      from RelatedTablesHierarchy as RTH inner join
        RelatedTables as RT on RT.ParentTableObjectId = RTH.ForeignTableObjectId
      -- NB: Avoid getting caught in reference loops.
      where '»' + Path + '»' not like '%»' + RT.ForeignTable + '»%'
      )
    -- Output the results with   Path   made a little easier to read.
    select Replace( Path, '»', ' » ' ) as Path, ParentTable, ParentTableObjectId, ForeignTable, ForeignTableObjectId
      from RelatedTablesHierarchy
      order by Path;
```

The initial query is certainly carrying some extra baggage, but you will need it to determine the table and column names necessary for joins. (Tip: Use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) when assembling object names into statements.)

NB: The common table expression is resistant to reference loops, e.g. tables that have foreign key references to themselves as well as longer loops involving multiple tables.